# NSString with HTML code to NSData

Tags: nsstring, nsdata

Thanks in advance!
I'm wondering if it's possible to convert HTML code stored in a NSString to a NSData to parse later.
I'm reading from a BBDD the HTML code and saving it into a NSString.

```
NSString *htmlString =@"<html><body><p>introduccion</p><p>introducción</p></body></html>";
```

I want to use:

NSData *nsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

But instead of initWithContentsOfURL i have to use the htmlString because I have the code stored in a BBDD and I am accessing it and storing the code to a NSString

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use standard methods to convert NSString to NSData like this:

```
NSData* data = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't works for me
I'm trying with this:

    NSString *htmlString = @"... SOME HTML CODE....";

NSData* nsData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

I have some html formatted text in my "subject.details", I add some more html formatting on the front and back. Giving me a "detailsStringForDisplay" NSString.

I convert this string to an NSData.
Set up a dictionary, which only contains one element to say that the document type is HTML.

Then finally set an attributedText using the data and the dictionary.

```
        NSString *fontDetailsHTML = @"<div style=\"font-size:17px; text-family:Georgia; \">";
        NSString *detailsString = subject.details;
        NSString *endFontDetailsHTML = @"</div>";
        NSString *detailsStringForDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",fontDetailsHTML,detailsString,endFontDetailsHTML];
        NSData *labelTextData = [detailsStringForDisplay dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:true];

    NSDictionary *attributesForText = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute , nil];

    self.detailDescriptionLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithData:labelTextData options:attributesForText documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```